# Pesky Link Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 and believe I have a project settings issue. I have a header file that has some declarations in it:

definitions.h

```
#include <string>

struct myStruct
{
    std::string x[4];
    std::string y[8];
};

void InitializeStructData();

extern myStruct data[12];
```

and the cpp file initializes my structure:

definitions.cpp

```
#include "definitions.h"
#include <string>

mySturct data[12];

void InitializeStructData()
{
    data[0].x[0] = "a";
    data[0].x[1] = "b";
    ....
    data[0].y[0] = "a";
    ....
    ....
    data[11].y[7] = "done initializing"';
}
```

and I have a form that has some buttons and things whose text I populate from the arrays depending on different circumstances:

myForm.cpp

```
#include "definitions.h"

... 

//form initialization
```

As soon as I have two `#include "definitions.h"` statements I get link errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > * Definitions" 
Error   2   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Comment: I wasn't really sure if the function was necessary for initializing, I did not have that in the original code. That is just me trying to come up with my own solutions. I'm stumped.

Comment: Your testcase is clearly not verbatim; the errors don't match the code, and you have a typo in `definitions.cpp`. Please make a proper testcase that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to make the problem more clear and smaller than my actual code. I will fix.

Comment: You were right to create a minimal testcase, but alas it wasn't a _complete_ one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is missing the important part.

You have a `std::string* Definitions` in a header, that you forgot to use `extern` with.

Comment: I can't believe it's still a problem on this site. :/

Comment: @GMan: Probably just a troll. Hopefully the automated systems will take care of it overnight. :)

Comment: @Tomalak - I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. What did I not use extern with?

Comment: @JoLT: Well you know what `extern` does, as you wrote `extern myStruct data[12];`. The error message indicates that you also have a `std::string* Definitions` that ought to be given the same treatment as your `myStruct data[12]`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your code (.h file) inside:

```
#ifndef DEFINITIONS_H
#define DEFINITIONS_H

#endif
```

to help prevent you from defining it multiple times, if you have it included in multiple places?

Comment: This will _not_ prevent problems with multiple definitions across multiple Translation Units. Only with compiler redefinitions _within a single_ TU. (Though header guards _are_ recommended; it's simply not the solution to this problem.)